# Trouble configuring eth0 static ip raspberry pi 4

Tags: static, ip, raspberry-pi4

I am new at this world, an I an having some trouble setting my raspberry pi 4.I want to set two static ip directions on it:

- When it is conected through eth0, I want it to have 192.168.1.250
- When it is conected through wifi, I want it to have 192.168.1.251

The first thing I notice is that when it is connected trough eth0 without any configuration, it gets the ip 169.254.193.232. I access to Wireless and Network Settings and I try to change it directly, but if I to that, it loses conection and it changes to WiFi.

But if I configure Wlan0 with the same method, it changes the IP without problem.

So, I decided to copy the settings on `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` from wlan0 to eth0. Then I disconect wifi to force it to conect through eth, and the raspberry loses conection.

Extra info: I have tried changing `/etc/network/interfaces`, but I get this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

So I think that the problem must be in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

This is what I get from `ifconfig` after changing wlan0 but before changing eth0:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 169.254.193.232  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
    inet6 fe80::178c:ecb5:b869:62c3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether dc:a6:32:df:6e:95  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 32358  bytes 3890697 (3.7 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 101  bytes 19401 (18.9 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 5  bytes 284 (284.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 5  bytes 284 (284.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.251  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::abda:3588:750f:6600  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether dc:a6:32:df:6e:96  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 44354  bytes 4776027 (4.5 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 25952  bytes 6647013 (6.3 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem. My router was misconfigured, and it was preventing the Raspberry to get an IP adress.
I won't experimtent with MAC filtering again